# Using Sepolia Testnet --> Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]

Tags: smartcontracts, metamask, etherscan

The background of my topic is e-commerce using smart contract, I need to create a escrow account to allow customer to send funds, instead of directly transferring the funds to the seller, until the customer received the items they bought. I'm using SepoliaETH to test my smart contract performance between Metamask and Solidity Remix Ide. I have set enough gas limit, but I'm confused about this error: Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted] , and don't know where are the mistakes. Can anyone help, please? thanks~

Transaction failure:
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x5e4a660fd2d8cdfebdd027de9784c04fd9f00fbdace40a95b6d033dab6b8d012

Comment: Please provide debugging details to reproduce the issue... Based on [Tenderly](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/sepolia/0x5e4a660fd2d8cdfebdd027de9784c04fd9f00fbdace40a95b6d033dab6b8d012) debugger it seems that the transaction aims to deploy a contract and that there's an uncaught exception during the execution of the constructor.